What is this carved greenish stone statue?
I found this at an antique store in Michigan.  It appears to have a face on either side of the head, and only one visible eye on each face.  Also odd is that it has feet facing opposite directions. Its hands are clutching its large stomach.

Hi and welcome to HistSE. Can we get a pic of the other side? Also, are there any marking on the base?

Does it have arms, hands and pregnant-looking belly on both sides ?

Could you also edit your question to include the general region where this was found.

I'm new to this, and I could only figure out how to add one photo.

Unfortunately,  there's nothing in the way of labels or inscriptions for me to get further information.

Evargalo- that's exactly how it looks. Very prominent belly, and exposed buttocks on the other side. Arms are holding its belly.

JustCal- I found this at an antique shop in Michigan,  so I'm not sure of its origin.  My gut says African,  but I'm not knowledgeable enough to be sure. I tried Google image search to see if I could find similar items.  I have something I bought in Michigan near me that is similar,  but carved from wood.

I'm definitely no expert, but the tooling marks on it look like ones you get from modern tools. I'm picking less than an arbitrary 70 years old and probably gift-shop item.
